# android how to sort images by name

Tags: java, android

Please any one help how to sort images by name.Here am sharing my code.please any one help.

Here am showing images with grid and list .How to sort images by name in grid and list view.Here am using menu by selecting sort by name and sort by size.

```
 // Main Activity
            public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
                public RelativeLayout mainLayout;
                View gridView,listView;
                CountryAdapterList customListAdapter;
                CountryAdapter cutomArrayAdapter;
                public int swithNo=0;
                public String[] country_Names;
                public RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
                public int[] country_Images = {R.drawable.banglades, R.drawable.bangladesh,
                        R.drawable.brazi, R.drawable.brazil, R.drawable.chin,
                        R.drawable.china, R.drawable.indi, R.drawable.india,
                        R.drawable.indonesi, R.drawable.indonesia, R.drawable.japa,
                        R.drawable.japan, R.drawable.nigeri, R.drawable.nigeria,
                        R.drawable.pakista, R.drawable.pakistan, R.drawable.russi,
                        R.drawable.russia, R.drawable.unitedstate,
                        R.drawable.unitedstates };
                public String[] country_Name_Sort = { "Bangladesh A", "Pakistan",
                        "Brazil A", "Brazil", "China A","Bangladesh", "China", "India A", "India",
                        "Indonesia A", "Russia","Indonesia", "Japan A", "Japan", "Nigeria A",
                        "Nigeria", "Pakistan A",  "Russia A", 
                        "UnitesStates A", "UnitesStates" };
                public float[] country_Image_size = {1.36f , 1.36f, 4.12f, 4.12f, 1.47f,
                        1.47f, 1.79f, 1.79f, 0.299f, 0.299f, 1.50f, 1.50f, 0.285f, 0.285f,
                        1.85f, 1.85f, 0.330f, 0.330f, 3.42f, 3.42f };


                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    // Creating a new RelativeLayout
                     relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
                    customListAdapter = new CountryAdapterList(getApplicationContext(),
                            country_Name_Sort, country_Image_size, country_Images);
                     cutomArrayAdapter=new CountryAdapter(getApplicationContext(), country_Name_Sort, country_Image_size, country_Images);
                    // Defining the RelativeLayout layout parameters.
                    // In this case I want to fill its parent
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
                    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(rlp);
                    gridView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_deatails_grid,
                            null);
                    listView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main_listview,
                            null);
                    setViewUpdate(swithNo);

                    ((AdapterView<ListAdapter>) gridView).setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
                            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CountryDetailsScreen.class);

                            i.putExtra("Position", position);
                            i.putExtra("Country_Name", country_Name_Sort);
                            i.putExtra("Country_image", country_Images);
                            i.putExtra("Country_Image_size", country_Image_size);
                            startActivity(i);

                        }
                    });
                    ((AdapterView<ListAdapter>) listView).setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CountryDetailsScreen.class);
                            i.putExtra("Position", position);
                            i.putExtra("Country_Name", country_Name_Sort);
                            i.putExtra("Country_image", country_Images);
                            i.putExtra("Country_Image_size", country_Image_size);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }

                    });
                }
                private void sortAscending () {
                    List<String> sortedMonthsList = Arrays.asList(country_Name_Sort);
                    Collections.sort(sortedMonthsList);
                    country_Name_Sort = (String[]) sortedMonthsList.toArray();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                    menu.add(1, 1, 0, "Grid View");
                    menu.add(1, 2, 1, "List View");
                    menu.add(2, 3, 2, "Sort By Name");
                    menu.add(2, 4, 3, "Sort By Size");
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
                    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
                    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case 1:
                        Log.d("SwithNo", "One");
                        swithNo=0;
                        setViewUpdate(swithNo);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Log.d("SwithNo", "Two");
                        swithNo=1;
                        setViewUpdate(swithNo);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Log.d("SwithNo", "Three");
                        sortAscending();
                        for(int i=0;i<country_Name_Sort.length;i++)
                        {
                            Log.e("Assending    ", " "+country_Name_Sort[i]);
                        }
                        ((ListView) listView).setAdapter(customListAdapter);
                        listView.invalidate();
                        setViewUpdate(swithNo);

                        break;
                    case 4 : Log.d("Switch", "Four");
                    }

                    return true;
                }
                public void setViewUpdate(int k)
                {
                    ((GridView) gridView).setAdapter(cutomArrayAdapter);
                    ((ListView) listView).setAdapter(customListAdapter);
                    relativeLayout.removeAllViews();
                    if(k==0)
                    {
                        relativeLayout.addView(gridView);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        relativeLayout.addView(listView);
                    }

                    setContentView(relativeLayout);

                }

            }

            class Country {
                int imageId;
                String countryName;

                Country(int imageId, String countyName) {
                    this.imageId = imageId;
                    this.countryName = countyName;
                }
            }

            class CountryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
                ArrayList<Country> list;
                Context context;
                String[] country_Name_Sort;

                CountryAdapter(Context context,String[] country_Name_Sort,float[] country_Image_size,int[] country_Images) {
                    this.context = context;
                    this.country_Name_Sort=country_Name_Sort;
                    list = new ArrayList<Country>();
                    /*Resources resource = context.getResources();
                    String[] country_Names = resource.getStringArray(R.array.coutry_names);*/
                    for (int i = 0; i < country_Name_Sort.length; i++) {
                        Country country = new Country(country_Images[i], country_Name_Sort[i]);
                        list.add(country);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return list.size();
                }

                @Override
                public Object getItem(int position) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return list.get(position);
                }

                @Override
                public long getItemId(int position) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return position;
                }

                class ViewHolder {
                    ImageView county_Image;
                    TextView country_Name;

                    ViewHolder(View v) {
                        county_Image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                        country_Name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.countryName);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
                    View row = convertView;
                    if (row == null) {
                        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context
                                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        row = inflator.inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);
                        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(row);
                        row.setTag(viewHolder);
                    } else {
                        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
                    }
                    Country cntry = list.get(position);
                    viewHolder.county_Image.setImageResource(cntry.imageId);
                    viewHolder.country_Name.setText(cntry.countryName);

                    return row;
                }
            }
                class CountryAdapterList extends BaseAdapter {
                    ArrayList<Country> list;
                    Context context;
                    String[] country_Name_Sort;
                    int[] country_Images;

                    CountryAdapterList(Context context,String[] country_Name_Sort,float[] country_Image_size,int[] country_Images) {
                        this.context = context;
                        this.country_Name_Sort=country_Name_Sort;
                        this.country_Images=country_Images;
                        list = new ArrayList<Country>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < country_Name_Sort.length; i++) {
                            Country country = new Country(country_Images[i], country_Name_Sort[i]);
                            list.add(country);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getCount() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return list.size();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Object getItem(int position) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return list.get(position);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public long getItemId(int position) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return position;
                    }

                    class ViewHolder {
                        ImageView county_Image;
                        TextView country_Name;

                        ViewHolder(View v) {
                            county_Image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewList);
                            country_Name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.countryNameList);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
                        View row = convertView;
                        if (row == null) {
                            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context
                                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                            row = inflator.inflate(R.layout.single_item_listview, parent, false);
                            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(row);
                            row.setTag(viewHolder);
                        } else {
                            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
                        }
                        Country cntry = list.get(position);
                        viewHolder.county_Image.setImageResource(cntry.imageId);
                        viewHolder.country_Name.setText(cntry.countryName);

                        return row;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: did you got the solution r still you stucked in the same @Thej

Comment: Hi King of Masses, I sorted images but images are not sorted by name.please help

Comment: instead of images , country_Name sorted ? by using my approach

Answer (score 1):

By using array sorting you can sort your image names in your application

```
//String array
    String[] strNames = new String[]{"John", "Alex", "Chris", "Williams", "Mark", "Bob"};
```

sort String array using sort method

```
 Arrays.sort(strNames);
```

Output of above given Java Sort String Array example would be
    String array sorted (case sensitive)

```
Alex
Bob
Chris
John
Mark
Williams
```

In the same way, before setting your array data to your lisyt view you can sort it by using Arrays.sort(strNames);

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

you should implement Java's Comparator.

```
ListView list;
    //fill list here.
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
      public int compare(final String a, final String b) {
        return a.compareTo(b));
      }
    });
```

you can compare objects too, using their properties.

```
public int compare(final LatLong a, final  LatLong b) {
    return a.latitude.compareTo(b.latitude));
  }
```